# spaCy NER training new model issues

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to train spacy to recognize a new entity, and this entity only. so in my code, I load the 'en' model and doing:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', create_make_doc=WhitespaceTokenizer)
nlp.entity.add_label("ANIMAL")
```

and for each train document I'm doing:

```
doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text) 
gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=tags) 
nlp.tagger(doc) 
loss = nlp.entity.update(doc, gold)
```

after finish everything, i'm doing:

```
nlp.end_training() 
nlp.save_to_directory('...')
```

now, i want to test my model. I have 2 pieces of codes:
1. right after the nlp.save_to_directory, i'm continue to load the test data:

```
result = nlp(text) 
animals = list(str(i) for i in result.ents)
```

2. i'm packaging the whole thing and using pip install, and then in another python file i'm loading the model:

   nlp = spacy.load(model_name)

and then continue with the same code:

```
result = nlp(text) 
animals = list(str(i) for i in result.ents)
```

In my opinion both of the options should retrieve exactly the same result, but i'm getting better results with the first option...
anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by saving the vocabulary to a file and load it again when loading the model